# Get creation date with format

Tags: powershell

I want to loop over images and move each into a folder of the creation date, but I seem to fail to see the point about how to format the resulting datetime string and maybe also how ChildItem works...

I intend to create a variable containing the correct formatted string of the creation date "2017-03-06", so that I can create a directory with that name and move the file there. This shall happen within a loop (`for`, `foreach`, ...).

```cs
$files = Get-ChildItem "P:\photos\"

for ($i=0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) {
    $outfile = $files[$i].FullName
    Write-Host "file: " $outfile
    $CreationDateStr = Get-ChildItem  $files[$i].CreationTime |
                       Get-Date -f "yyyy-MM-dd"
    Write-Host "file creation time: " $CreationDateStr
}

Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

This does not work, and the code is not correct:

> Get-ChildItem : The disc was not found. Not disc with name "03/06/2017 07"

This works, but it needs to be formatted:

```
$files[$i].CreationTime
```

> file creation time:  06.03.2017 07:53:21

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't recommend `Write-Host` because you can't redirect it.

Here's what I think you are looking for:

```
Get-ChildItem "P:\Photos" | ForEach-Object {
  $dirName = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" -f $_.CreationTime
  if ( -not (Test-Path $dirName -PathType Container) ) {
    [Void] (New-Item $dirName -ItemType Directory)
  }
  Move-Item $_ $dirName -WhatIf
}
```

So in the loop, we check if the specified directory doesn't exist (create it if it doesn't), then move the file to the new directory. Remove `-WhatIf` if the code does what you want.

Comment: Done. I want a loop over images in a folder and move each into a folder of the creation date.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech I recommend deleting your comments on my answer as it is now updated.